# VCSupdate plugin installation

Tags: plugins, teamcity

I'm trying to install VCSupdate.zip in teamcity but the instructions online are for TeamCity 4.  I'm using the newest version which is 5.1.2 so it doesn't have the data directory like the old one does.  How do I install this plugin?  Also, if i need to restart teamcity how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.  The .zip files needs to be placed in the plugin folder which is found in your home directory .buildServer directory.   To restart teamcity you can go into administrative tools and click on services on windows and click restart on teamcity server.